# Would global variable be copied (in RAM) to each processor on each worker?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say that I have large `rdd`, and I want to apply function that uses a global. My question is: how many times the global gets copied.

Let's say that I have a driver node and 2 worker nodes, where each worker has 4 processors. Would the global variable be copied (in RAM) 8 times (for each processor on each worker node)? The number of partitions that rdd has is not relevant (as long it is not less than 8), right?

In other words, if my global/shared data structure takes up 100 MBs of RAM it would take up 400 MBs RAM on a given worker if a worker has 4 processors, right?

Following is a pseudo-codish example of what I am talking about:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="myApp)

my_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4} # at no point will be modified

def my_func(letter):
    return my_dict[letter]

my_list_rdd = # Make my rdd

result = my_list_rdd.map(lambda x: my_func(x))

# do something with result
```

I know that I should probably use `broadcast` here, but I trying to make sure that I understand what is going in case of globals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables)

> Spark automatically broadcasts the common data needed by tasks within each stage. The data broadcasted this way is cached in serialized form and deserialized before running each task.

Since PySpark executes tasks in separate interpretes with *n*  active workers and *m* partitions variable has to be transfered *n* times and deserialized *m* times (once for each active Python process). So the top memory usage in PySpark should be roughly `size-of-serialized-structure` + `#python-processes` * `size-of-deserialized-structure`.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but I still don't completely understand. If a worker node has 4 cores, 4 tasks will be run on that worker. After an object has been deserialized it is strored in RAM, and this will happen 4 times on the worker, for each task. So shared variable will be stored in RAM 4 times on the worker? That is my understanding, is it wrong?

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank You.